# JQuery function for button click on html page 1, affects columns of html page 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am trying to figure out how to take user button clicks from `buttons.html` to dynamically toggle column visibility on a second `userinput.html`.  I'm using DataTables for the `userinput.html` table and thought I had the solution with `column.visible`.  In the DataTables manual there is an example of clicking a `<a>` and toggling column visibility.  I am trying to apply that logic across html files.  Unfortunately, the code I've tried is not working.  Here's what I've got:

BUTTON PAGE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>buttons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="designscratchpad.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Button page</h1>

<button id='id1' class='class1' data-column="1">Clickme</button>
<button id='id2' class='class1' data-column="2">Clickme</button>
<button id='id3' class='class1' data-column="3">Clickme</button>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jqc-1.12.4/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/r-2.1.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='stackexample.js'>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

USER INPUT PAGE

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jqc-1.12.4/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/r-2.1.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.css"/>
<body>
<table id="userinput" class="display" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>   
        <tr class="ac">
            <td>
                <input type="text" autofocus placeholder="e.g; " name="input" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="" name="P" class="h"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jqc-1.12.4/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/r-2.1.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='stackexample.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#userinput').DataTable(  {
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "scrollX" : true,
        "scrollY" : true,
        "scrollCollapse" : true,
        "searching" : false,
        // "stateSave" : true,
      });

    $('button.class1').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the column API object
        var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );
});
;
```

There are no errors in the console on either html page.  I think the error may be the use of the `this` keyword, but I'm not sure how to adjust the code to apply across html files.

It's not required to have the buttons on a separate page, in fact, I'd gratefully accept any constructive criticism.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can click button on one page to toggle (or any effect) on your another page ? So you can use webStorage(localstorage, sessionstorga) or cookies (read aboit this) or somthing like this. You click button and use script on first page but when you skip to another your js is restarting so you want to somthing to storage your data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Emil.  Just to make sure I understand, if I use localStorage I will be able to track which buttons the user selects on buttons.html, and when they move to the userinput.html page they will see columns that have been made visible/hidden by the JS.  Right?